# Change transparency of image at runtime, LOVE2D

Tags: graphics-programming, lua, love2d

I would like to know how to take a defined image (e.g. a tile) in the LOVE game engine and draw it with a transparency that may vary per-frame. Stencils seem to only work for completely hiding parts of an image; I need to make an entire tile translucent, and the degree of translucency needs to be able to vary during gameplay.

(purpose: I am messing around with a game idea that involves partial information during fog-of-war, represented by superimposing all tiles that might be somewhere based on what you currently know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the color to white-with-less-than-full alpha before drawing the image. For instance, this would draw your image at around 50% opacity:

```
love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255, 128)
love.graphics.draw(image, 0, 0)
```

The easiest way to work with this if you want to fade something in / out is to have a fractional multiplier value from 0 to 1 and set the alpha component to 255 * that, i.e.

```
love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255, 255 * someMultiplier)
```

Comment: `setColor` takes values in the range 0-1, so it should be `love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5)`

Comment: That’s true as of version 11, which is newer than this answer. From the [wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setColor): “In versions prior to 11.0, color component values were within the range of 0 to 255 instead of 0 to 1.”